# How can I find out idle node in Elasticsearch cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using AWS Elasticsearch 6.8 and configured 9 nodes, 5 replicas shard, 1 primary shard. There are only 6 shards which means only 6 nodes are required. 
Is one shard can only exist in one node? If yes, there should be 3 idle nodes in the cluster and how I can find out which of the 3 nodes are idle?

If there are 3 idle nodes, whether it impacts search? When the cluster receives a request, will it send the request to one of the idle node?

Comment: `_cat/shards` shows which shard is on which node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right, but in your case, we need some more information like our of 9 nodes, how many are **dedicated master nodes**(as on master nodes, shards(which actually contains) data is not allocated ).

If you are having all 9 data nodes, and just one index with 1 primary and 5 replica shards, then certainly they all will be allocated on different nodes(except in some weird rare case).

using the [cerebo elasticsearch cluster-admin tool](https://github.com/lmenezes/cerebro), you can quickly point your Elasticsearch cluster, and get to know what all nodes are there in your cluster and how shards(replicas and primary) allocated on them.

Below is the sample of how nodes and index created in my AWS-elasticsearch looks like. **clearly you can see, my own index has (1 primary shard and 0 replica shard and ES cluster has just 1 node and that shard is allocated on that node).**

[image: cerebo es cluster image]

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you know a bulid-in feature to support that?

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao as you are using AWS hosted elasticsearch and even APIs are also not provide results in visual format, so it's difficult, also cerebo you can install using docker and doesn't take more than 10 minutes and after that makes such tasks very easy.